# Mass updating of database fields from Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I have a Rails 3.2.19 app where I have a call model and a region model.

Call belongs_to :region and has region_id in the table
Region has_many :calls and the field I'm interested in is in the Region model called area which is a string type that contains a City (Houston, Dallas).

My question is.  I have nearly 18K call records where I need to update the region_id to the region's area.  i.e "1" or "2"

What's the best way to update this region_id field via the console or even better yet via PSQL which we use as a database?

I know this is probably a simple thing but I want to make sure I don't cause problems in production.

Comment: "Best" in what way? "Not causing problems" seems more a matter of doing it *correctly*.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear.  I meant best as in doing it correctly.  I've called update_attribute on a single object before via the Rails console but haven't iterated through 18K records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [update_all](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all)

```
Call.where(area: 'Houston').update_all(region_id: 1)
```

To update calls which doesn't have region_id

```
Call.where("region_id IS NULL").update_all(region_id: 1)
```

Comment: The above doesn't work since there's no area object in Call.  If I want to update all of the records to region_id 1 I think this will work: `Call.update_all region_id: 1`

Comment: you suggested that such column exists " the field I'm interested in is ```area``` which is a string type that contains a City (Houston, Dallas)". You can filter records using where and update only selected using update_all with value.

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited my question to make it more clear.  The field area is actually in the Region model. For this instance, I need to update 18K records which do not have a region_id to to 1.